# Call instance function from app delegate

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a class called game.h and it has an instance method called pause. How can I call this from app delegate when my game goes into the background?

I know that you use `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`, but I want to call pause on my existing instance.

Comment: Your app delegate will need a reference to the specific Game instance you wish to pause. There is not enough information here to suggest how to provide that instance to the app delegate. Who creates the Game and might make it available to the app delegate?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true Jonah.  In fact, giving the app delegate a reference to the game class to keep track of can quickly become messy.  You can just use notifications.

Comment: It is a skscene within the initial view controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `NSNotificationCenter`.

In your instance of the `game` class, add `self` as an observer to the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification.

---

In your `game` class, somewhere, you need the following snippet:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(pause) 
    name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
    object:nil];
```

This should probably go in `init`.

This notification is fired by `applicationWillResignActive`.  The `addObserver:selector:name:object:` method sets your object up to call the selector you tell it whenever it receives that notification.'

---

Don't forget to remove `self` as an observer in `dealloc`.

In `game.m`'s `@implementation`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    // If not using ARC, then be sure to [super dealloc];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: How do I remove self as an observer?

Comment: @maxhud Just call `removeObserver:name:object:` (same syntax as above, except no `selector` parameter). Most people will add observer when the object is loaded and remove it in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: @maxhud If your class doesn't have a `dealloc` method, just add one and this is the only thing you have to put into it (assuming you're using ARC). If not ARC, then add call to `[super dealloc]` in there, too.

Comment: @maxhud I updated the answer to show you how to remove observer.